# How to compare array values with another set of array values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, encryption, compare

I am trying to make a playfair cipher square generator.

If you know what that is then you know that you have a key that then goes in to a square where the rest of the alphabet that isnt in the key gets entered in alphabetical order(also the J key is removed).

So at the moment I have this function:

```
function square(usrInputKey){
    var alpha = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
    var key = usrInputKey.toUpperCase()
    keyword = key.split('')
    var keysquare=keyword
    count=keyword.length
    for (var p=0;p<alpha.length;p++) {
        //document.write(" Alpha: " + alpha[p] + "<br>")
        if ( keyword[0] != alpha[p] && keyword[1] != alpha[p] && keyword[2] != alpha[p] ) {
            keysquare[count]=alpha[p]
            count++
        }
    }
            return keysquare
}
```

That function has the input of the keyword that is the word key for testing perposes.

This function works, output is: K,E,Y,A,B,C,D,F,G,H,I,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Z

However it only works if keyword is the length of 3 characters. I would like it if it works with a keyword of any amount rather than hard code the 3 or have and statements for different possible lengths.

I have tried .every() but that just checks the array characters one at a time and ouputs the key and then the full alphabet including the letters that were in the key.

Can anyone solve this issue? or does it have to be hardcoded to a certain key length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a working example. The join and console.log were for my convenience.

```
function square(usrInputKey){
  var alpha =  ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
  var key = usrInputKey.toUpperCase();
  keyword = key.split('');
  var newAlpha = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < alpha.length; k++) {
    found = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < key.length; j++) {
      if (alpha[k].indexOf(key[j]) > -1){
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (!found){
      newAlpha.push(alpha[k]);
    }
  }
  newArray = keyword.concat(newAlpha);
  return newArray.join(',');
}
console.log(square('KEYWORD'));
```

Also, its a very good idea to make use of semi-colons where appropriate (line endings etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that generates the desired table, along with some jasmine tests, just because:

```
describe('Key generator test', function () {

    var wordControl = {};
    var alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',  'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

    beforeEach(function() {
        alphabet.forEach(function(letter) {
            wordControl[letter] = 0;
        });
    });

    function square(key) {
        var result = [];
        key = key.toUpperCase();
        key = key.replace('J', 'I');
        var keyArray = key.split('');
        keyArray.forEach(function(letter) {
            if(wordControl[letter] == 0) {
                result.push(letter);
                wordControl[letter] = 1;
            }
        });

        alphabet.forEach(function(letter) {
            if(wordControl[letter] == 0) {
                result.push(letter);
            }
        });

        return result;
    }

    it('should generate a table starting with tke key followed by the sorted alphabet', function() {
        var key = 'KAWABANGA';
        var generatedTable = square(key);
        expect(generatedTable.join('')).toEqual('KAWBNGCDEFHILMOPQRSTUVXYZ');
    });

    it('should replace J with I', function() {
        var key = 'JONAS';
        var generatedTable = square(key);
        expect(generatedTable.join('')).toEqual('IONASBCDEFGHKLMPQRTUVWXYZ');
    });

    it('should not fail due to key being more than 25 characters', function() {
        var key = 'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMMNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ';
        var generatedTable = square(key);
        expect(generatedTable.join('')).toEqual('QWERTYUIOPASDFGHKLZXCVBNM');
    });
});
```

I guess you still have to transform the resulting array in a 5x5 matrix in order to continue with the playfair cipher algorithm. Let me know if you run into any more trouble.